# Can't remove empty rows from CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

I have empty rows in cvs file:

```
CSV.table(filepath).count { |row| row.to_h.values.all?(&:blank?) }
#=> 6
```

I am trying to delete these using [CSV::Table#`delete_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html#method-i-delete_if):

```
CSV.table(filepath).delete_if { |row| row.to_h.values.all?(&:blank?) }
#=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:6>
```

Here I would expect my csv to no longer contain empty rows, but:

```
CSV.table(filepath).count { |row| row.to_h.values.all?(&:blank?) }
#=> 6
```

Am I missing some point here? I checked if [`CSV::Table`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html) has something like `delete_if!`, but it does not, so assumingly what I have should work.

Comment: At each command, you are reloading the file, no? And you are assuming Rails tooling?

Comment: Why do you think that if `delete_if!` doesn't exist, then `delete_if` should work like that?

Comment: The CSV table is built in memory. Unless you are saving the CSV to `filepath` after the `delete_if`, the next `CSV.table(filepath)` will read the original content again.

Comment: @Doguita You are absolutely right. CVS is a drugstore!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of `delete_if` states:

> This method returns the table for chaining.

So you get the table back and I guess you are expected to save it to some CSV then again. It does not modify the original CSV file.

You need to store it then again: `File.write('/path/new_name.csv', csv.to_s)`

Comment: Or, alternatively, the OP should have saved the result like `csv = CSV.table(filepath).delete_if{...}`, then have done `csv.count ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CSV.table(filepath, skip_blanks: true)
```

causes CSV to ignore empty rows.